# Adding another row to Mat object

Tags: opencv, matrix, row

I'm basically trying to ad another row to a 2x3 homography matrix that I found out using findHomography() function.

```
    Mat insert = (Mat_<double>(1,3)<<0 , 0 , 1);
    Mat homography = findHomography(features1 , features2 , CV_RANSAC);
    resize(affine , affine , Size(3,3));
    homgraphy.push_back(insert);
    cout<<"Homography"<<" "<<homography;
```

But when I print homography the 3rd row doesn't have two zero's but very small number's. I want the last row to be exactly {0 , 0 , 1}. How I can I do that?

Comment: You have not shown sufficient context to be able to determine the problem. The issue could be with how you are printing the homography, e.g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find what is corrupting the matrix (try printing out `insert` to see if it has changed), you could force the issue with

```
Mat insert = (Mat_<double>(1,3)<<0 , 0 , 1);
Mat homography = findHomography(features1 , features2 , CV_RANSAC);
resize(affine , affine , Size(3,3));
homgraphy.push_back(insert);     // ADD EXTRA ROW TO HOMOGRAPHY RESULT

homgraphy.at<Vec3d>(2,0) = Vec3d(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);  // OVERWRITE BOTTOM ROW OF MAT
```

Comment: When I use the above statement it gives me the following error   Error: corrupted double-linked list: 0x000000000240ae70 ***.  How can I correct it?

Comment: Sounds like the heap is corrupted. That message is coming from the C++ run-time library, I think, and not from OpenCV.  BTW are you compiling for debug?

Comment: Yes I compiled for debugging. It seems like the last row was corrupted. But it's working now as I overwrote it. Thanks!